# Can I create custom metrics on grafana service accounts?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

We have service accounts that customers can use to interact with our grafana instance, I have basic metrics from grafana that I used to make a prometheus server and that allows counting the number of service accounts and tokens. How can I create a custom metric on service acccounts ?

This is a spike, not sure if possible to implement.